# Could not determine polymorphic type because input has type "unknown"

Tags: sql, database, string, postgresql, polymorphism

I have a query which gives output as

> Could not determine polymorphic type because input has type "unknown"

**Query :**

```
select ( array_to_string(array_agg(name), ', '))::text as name,path 
from(select 'fullpath' as Path,null as id,'' as name 
     from tblabc where key = 'key1' and value = '1' 
    ) as e 
group by path;
```

I have a **postgres** database

Comment: Cast the NULL to some datatype or drop it because you don't use it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The issue here is that `'' as name` doesn't actually specify a type for the value. It's the `unknown` type, and PostgreSQL usually infers the real type from things like what column you're inserting it into or what function you pass it to.

In this case, you pass it to `array_agg`, which is a *polymorphc* function. It can take inputs of the pseudo-type `anyelement`, which really just means "figure it out at runtime".

PostgreSQL would still figure it out except that `array_to_string` doesn't actually take a `text[]` as input. It takes `anyarray` - another polymorphic type, like `anyelement` for arrays.

So there's nothing in the query to tell PostgreSQL what type that `''` is. It could guess you meant `text`, but it's a bit too fussy for that. So it complains. The issue simplifies down to:

```
regress=> SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(''), ',');
ERROR:  could not determine polymorphic type because input has type "unknown"
```

To solve this, write a typed literal:

```
TEXT '' AS name
```

or use a cast:

```
CAST('' AS text) AS name
```

or the PostgreSQL shorthand:

```
''::text
```

examples:

```
regress=> SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(TEXT ''), ',');
 array_to_string 
-----------------

(1 row)

regress=> SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(''::text), ',');
 array_to_string 
-----------------

(1 row)

regress=> SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(CAST('' AS text)), ',');
 array_to_string 
-----------------

(1 row)
```

Comment: As per you said, I implement this but I got "failed to find conversion function from unknown to text"

Comment: @samkitshah Works for me. Show the query in an update to your question please. Also show `SELECT version()`;

Comment: Cast all your content to a specific type, text I guess, and test the query. If it fails again, please show us this new query. And try to update to a newer version, you're missing many many patches and 8.4 will be EOL within a few weeks maybe months.

Comment: @samkitshah Edit your question to show the updated query and exact text of the error or we cannot help you.