# Strange JSON interpretation (polymorphic type), how to workaround?

Tags: json, postgresql, casting, polymorphism

This legal(!) `CASE` construct returns a JSON datatype:

```
 SELECT CASE WHEN true THEN to_json(1) ELSE to_json('hello') END;
```

but:

> ERROR:  could not determine polymorphic type because input has type "unknown"

It is not "polymorphic", it is JSON.

... So, as **bad workaround** (lost number/string JSON representations),

```
 SELECT to_json(CASE WHEN true THEN 1::text ELSE 'hello' END);
```

Is there a better way to do this SQL-to-JSON cast?

Comment: JSON is not a datatype. JSON is an object notation for specifying data of arbitrary types. 1 is a number and "hello" is a string. You cannot specify a value which can either be a number or a string. The reason your workaround works is that 1::text or "1" is a string and now you're always building a string datatype. If you want to sometimes have a number and sometimes have a string, you can wrap this in a larger object. For example, {id: 1, word: ""} could be one output and {id: null, word: "hello"} could be another output and you could build these outputs based on the Boolean.

Comment: @anandsun hum... I agree about JSON "datatype" (do you have a ["official link"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html) asserting that we must ignore it as datatype?), but perhaps we can  think about JSONb as a real datatype...  MUST be a "first-class citizen" to make sense and be competitive with MongoDB, etc. noSQL.

Comment: As in the doc example, the cast is on the text: SELECT CASE WHEN true THEN to_json(1) ELSE to_json('hello'::text) END;

Comment: @peterkrauss You're probably right; in your use case json is a datatype, and this is not the cause of your technical issue. I don't know enough to solve this, which is why I made a comment and didn't give an answer. Even though your question says "legitime (!)", to me having an output that is conditionally typed is a code smell, and probably means something is wrong with the structure of the surrounding business logic. Is [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257726/could-not-determine-polymorphic-type-because-input-has-type-unknown](this link) relevant?

Comment: @JGH  your example is working? What postgresql version?

Comment: More one **ugly solution** `SELECT CASE WHEN true THEN json_build_object('result',1) ELSE json_build_object('result','hello') END`

Comment: @PeterKrauss yes, under 9.6.1  See [demo](http://rextester.com/EGCO39788)

Comment: Sorry all, I am testing @JGH solution and it is working also at pg9.5.6!  So, thanks JGH, please post it as solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do it the other way round:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN true THEN to_json(1) ELSE to_json(text 'hello') END;
```

Declare 'hello' as type `text`.
This way you retain `1` as number and `'hello'` as string.
The explicit cast `'hello'::text` is equivalent.

The reason is the Postgres type system. An unquoted `1` is a legal numeric constant and defaults to the Postgres data type `integer`. But `'hello'` (with single quotes) is a string literal that starts out as type `unknown`. The function `to_json()` is polymorphic, its input parameter is defined as `ANYELEMENT`. The output depends on the input data type. And it does not know what to do with data type `unknown`. Hence the error message.

The result data type is `json` in either case (which is a regular Postgres *data type*), but that is orthogonal to the problem.

Related:

- [No function matches the given name and argument types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24751372/no-function-matches-the-given-name-and-argument-types/24771122#24771122)
- [Is there a way to disable function overloading in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28698641/is-there-a-way-to-disable-function-overloading-in-postgres/28710225#28710225)